# portal texture problems

Tags: steam, portal

during the mid week madness sale on steam i purchased portal and portal 2. I ran portal and got up to testchamber 10 and all the textures are missing and everything is wrong and broken:

[screenshot http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/559811256398464676/913B72A9D4329954741AED4F84015ADBFF308DCA/](http://steamcommunity.com/id/x24aboVe/screenshot/559811256398464676?tab=public)

I updated my graphics driver for my nvidia geforce gt220 and reinstalled portal, this problem still occurs. any help would be aprecieated thanks.

Comment: woah, what did you smoke? :-P

Comment: can you load an older savegame and see if this happens again when you re-enter chamber 10?

Comment: any ideas to fix it?

Comment: i tried that the test chamber was still broken, i will try again now

Comment: i tried again, it still doesnt work

Comment: very weird... and it's fine until then? Did you restart your PC already?

Comment: Have you tried to verify the game cache ? if that doesn't come up with errors you could try to delete portal and all portal related .gcf files (steam/steamapps)

Comment: That looks *awesome*

Comment: Why do you _want_ to fix this?

Comment: i have restarted my pc once or twice since i got it. i have just verified the game cache and will run portal when it has finished updating.

Comment: @ Ronan Forman i want to fix this so i can play the game through again

Comment: @William So you had a first complete playthrough without any problem?

Comment: no, i have both portals on xbox and on pc (dont ask why, i know its stupid) i played through the first 2 on xbox and bought them for pc so i could play the 2nd co op with friends i know

Comment: What drivers are you running? Weird graphical artifacts like this always ring the "outdated/not properly installed drivers"-bell.

Comment: I've noticed this weird thing where if you noclip to the bottom of the elevator shaft, the weird light blue texture shows. If you're just in the elevator (no noclip, you're actually standing in the moving elevator), you may have a problem with either the texture of the door, or the door model itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Steam Library, Right click on Portal and select "Properties." In the following menu, go to "Local Files" and select "Verify Integrity of Game Cache..."

If this doesn't work, you may have to "Delete Local Content" and then re-download the game.

Comment: I'd say it's unlikely that deleting and redownloading would succeed if verifying did not, but verifying is certainly the right thing to do.

Comment: i have done this but now i have another problem, i cant launch portal because there is an update that is constantly suspended

Comment: @William only put a checkmark on this answer if it really solved your problem - were you able to start Portal and play test chamber 10 without any problems before this new problem occured? Re your new problem, you should [ask a new question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)